# Script that delete duplicated materials (from appending objects) and reassign the correct material

Tags: python

I need to make a script that delete duplicated materials (from appending objects) and reassign the materials with the same names to the same material slots. Could you help me figuring out how to do it?

Something like that:

```
bpy.ops.wm.append (autoselect = True)
    #Check if 'bpy.context.active_object.active_material' has a dot on 4th position from the end (since duplicated material are renamed mat.001)
        #if condition true delete the mat
        #reassign mat with same name minus the 4 last characters of the name string on the same material slot
```

Comment: Can you check if the object has a material with a given name?

Comment: if 'material name' in bpy.context.active_object.active_material.name

Comment: Check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119258/60759 It delas with textures, materials and even node groups. I haven't tested it thouroughly in 2.80 thoug, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object

for index in range(0, len(obj.material_slots.keys())):   

    obj.active_material_index = index

    if "." in obj.active_material.name:

        mat = obj.active_material.name[:-4]
        bpy.data.materials.remove(obj.active_material)
        obj.data.materials[index] = bpy.data.materials[mat]
```

This work, I kind of cheated with the if "."

Comment: But the size of `obj.data.materials` never changes. There is _duplication_ of material.

Comment: This: bpy.data.materials.remove(obj.active_material) delete the material completely from the blend file

Comment: Yes, the size of `bpy.data.materials` decreases but the size of `obj.data.materials` is constant.

Comment: blender 3.6.2 I cant access obj.data.materials but works with: `        for mat in objOld.material_slots:
            objNew.material_slots[iMatIndex].material=mat.material;
            iMatIndex+=1
`