# How to avoid material duplicates when appending multiple assets?

Tags: materials, objects, import, append, data-blocks

i just found a really odd behavior in blender:

---

**Actions:**

- 1) append an object that have the material named "Red"
- 2) append another object that have this same material
- 3) same with another.. ect..

**Result:**

you have now multiple material data: "Red" ,"Red.001" ,"Red.002" ect...
even tho all thoses assets had the same material "Red" at the first place..

---

This is a really odd behavior, any ways we can append while not dupplicating a material ? the only idea i had is making a script that handle the mess it create afterwards, but well, this mess shouldn't be there at the first place, so i'm sure there's a way to avoid this.

Is it ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155091/script-that-delete-duplicated-materials-from-appending-objects-and-reassign-th

Comment: Append creates copies completely independent of the original project. Therefore multiple appends create separate materials copies. You can link the material if you don't want to edit it (only reference the material from the other project). Library overrides would allow you to modify them locally without affecting the original. We would need to know what you're trying to do in order to recommend an approach. Perhaps you don't need to use append.